# Error using varMaskRegexes (MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper) in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm  generating a token from an api call and I want to mask its value to avoid displaying in the jenkins console. For that reason, I'm trying to use `varMaskRegexes` because I'm getting a token with the following format azAz09-azAz09. However, I'm getting an error because it seems to me that I'm not using it in the correct way. I can't store the token value in a envar because it must be generated, when the job is executed.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Secret-Masking') {
            steps {
                wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varMaskRegexes: [[key:'token',value:'([A-Za-z0-9]{5}+-[A-Za-z0-9]{5})']]]) { 
                  sh '''
                    token =$(curl -X POST  https://secret.api/getToken)
                    curl -H "Authorization:$token" https://secret.api/getJobinfo
                    curl -H "Authorization:$token" https://secret.api/revokeToken
                    '''
                }
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to remove the quotes from the regex expression but it didn't worked, so I think that is the issue.

The error I'm getting it's the following:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] {Secret-Masking
[Pipeline] { 
[Pipeline] wrap

WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.maskpasswords.MaskPasswordsConfig$VarMaskRegexEntry': name

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.maskpasswords.MaskPasswordsConfig$VarMaskRegexEntry.value expects class java.lang.String but received class com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.maskpasswords.MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper$VarMaskRegex
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:492)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:329)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {name=null, value=([[A-Za-z0-9]{5}+-[A-Za-z0-9]{5})} for com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.maskpasswords.MaskPasswordsConfig$VarMaskRegexEntry
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:474)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerceList(DescribableModel.java:585)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:458)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:329)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {varPasswordPairs=[], varMaskRegexes=[{value=([[A-Za-z0-9]{5}+-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}), key=token}]} for com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.maskpasswords.MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:474)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:329)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3296.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:180)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {delegate={$class=MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper, varPasswordPairs=[], varMaskRegexes=[{value=([[A-Za-z0-9]{5}+-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}), key=token}]}} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreWrapperStep
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3296.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:180)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:76)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(ModelInterpreter.groovy:137)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:666)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:395)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:393)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:665)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:288)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:539)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:90)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor278.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:152)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:146)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and document the concrete error message you're getting as well. These are important when you ask a question Also add all the relevant details. And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `varMaskRegexes` is a configuration option in Jenkins that allows you to define regular expressions to mask sensitive information (e.g. passwords, access tokens, etc.) in the console output.

To use this feature, you need to define the regular expression that matches the sensitive information and then add it to the `varMaskRegexes` configuration option. Here is an example of how you can use it to mask a token with the format you mentioned `(azAz09-azAz09)`:

**Code**

```
def token = 'abc123-def456' // replace with your actual token value
def varMaskRegexes = '([a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{6})'

echo "Token: ${token}" // will display the token value in the console

echo "Masked Token: ${token.replaceAll(varMaskRegexes, '********')}" // will display the masked token value in the console
```

In this example, the regular expression ([a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}) matches the token format `azAz09-azAz09`. Then, the `replaceAll` method is used to replace the matched token with ******** to mask it in the console output.

You can also add the regular expression to the `varMaskRegexes` configuration option in the Jenkinsfile or in the Jenkins system configuration, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, for my particular case the token is generated when the job is executed, so I can't store it in a envar. Then, when The token is generated its value is shown in the jenkins console. Could you show me how to modify the varMaskRegexes within jenkinsfile, please.